# How can I set a message unread?? with delphi 7 and imap from indy10

Tags: delphi, imap, delphi-7, indy, indy10

How can I set a email message unread??

Here I read the emails from inbox in gmail

When I read gmail, it flag like read, so I would like to flag like unread again.

```
 TheImap.GetUID(i+1, TheUID);
 TheImap.UIDRetrieveFlags(TheUID, TheFlags);
 TheImap.UIDRetrieveHeader(TheUID, TheMsg);
 TheImap.UIDRetrieveText(TheUID, lacadena);

 if mfSeen in TheFlags then begin
   TheImap.StoreFlags(TheUID, sdReplace, TheMsg.Flags - [mfSeen] );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass a UID string where a MsgNum integer is expected.  You need to use `UIDStoreFlags()` instead of `StoreFlags()`:

```
TheImap.UIDStoreFlags(TheUID, sdReplace, TheFlags - [mfSeen]);
```

Comment: the error it give me is incompatible types array and string 
  if mfSeen in TheFlags then begin
TheImap.StoreFlags(TheUID, sdReplace, TheMsg.Flags - [mfSeen] );

Comment: those are var
TheFlags: TIdMessageFlagsSet;
    TheUID: string;
      nCount: integer;
    TheMsg: TIdMessage;
    MailBoxName: string;
        lacadena:string;

    i: integer;
    bRet: Boolean;
      OpenSSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;

Comment: Again, you have to use `UIDStoreFlags()`, not `StoreFlags()`.  Notice the `UID` prefix on the method name.

Comment: ohh my mistake, testing now